# Drupal 7 Multiple Email Attachments

Tags: email, drupal, attachment

I am seeking help in getting this array fully functioning to send multiple email attachments. My code is below:

```
$params = array(
    'attachments' => array(

   0 => array(
    'filecontent' => file_get_contents("http://textfiles.com/100/914bbs.txt"),
    'filename' => 'some_file.txt'
    ),

   1 => array(
    'filecontent' => file_get_contents("http://textfiles.com/100/914bbs.txt"),
    'filename' => 'playa.txt'
    ),

   2 => array(
    'filecontent' => file_get_contents("http://textfiles.com/100/914bbs.txt"),
    'filename' => 'altered.txt'
    )

    )
 );
```

This code works fine for sending multiple emails, however I need this to be in some sort of loop instead of manually listing these out.

My Question is:

How can I put this in an array so when I call

```
$message = drupal_mail('emailFiles', 'notify', 'email@something.org', language_default(), $params);
```

$params will know the full array.

Thank you In advance for all your help!

I am just looking to make this array efficient with a loop, not another strategy of sending emails! I am using MimeMail to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Using a loop, I would put all attachments in an array

```
foreach($myfiles as $myfile) {
    $attachments[] = array(
        'filepath' => $myfile->uri,
        'filename' => $myfile->filename,
        'filemime' => $myfile->filemime,
       );
}
```

and then in the mail function try something like this:

```
foreach($attachments as $attachment) {
    $params['attachments'][] = $attachment;
}

drupal_mail('mymodule', 'mymailkey', $account['mail'], $language, $params, variable_get('site_mail'));
```